# Facebook link share image is distorted

Tags: html, facebook

I've got a website and have added appropriate og meta tags. The Facebook debug tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) even shows the correct og:image being pulled in. But for some reason, the preview of the link share is distorted. When I paste in the link it looks good while I edit a post, but then it only shows a zoomed-in portion of the bottom half of the image.

Any ideas? I'm at a loss.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title data-ng-bind-template="{{ vm.getPageTitle() }} - Still Memories Photography">Home - Still Memories Photography</title>
<meta name="description" content="Still Memories Photography. Portrait and wedding photographer located in Arvada Colorado.">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1 maximum-scale=1 user-scalable=no">
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.stillmemories.photography/Images/Assets/liasnow.jpg">
<meta property="og:title" content="Still Memories Photography">
<meta property="og:description" content="Portrait and wedding photographer located in Arvada, Colorado.">
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.stillmemories.photography">
<link href="/Content/css?v=E9KngqeJrvXl3d3KXxzuuUi9weaFZmoTKRiDWp8qamI1" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to use a bigger image. Facebook recommends 50x50 pixels as a minimum - which mine far exceeded (mine was 321x220). But for whatever reason it thought this was small and stretched it far out of proportion. Be sure to use a large image.

Comment: Don’t know where you got 50x50 pixels from – but the minimum image size has been 200x200 px for a long time already. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images